# How can I set alias names for hostname on Redhat?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, redhat, hostname

I'm aware that modifying `/etc/sysconfig/network` can set a permanent hostname for my server. But I also want to set some alias for it, and make several clients able to resolve them, how can I achieve this?

`/etc/hosts` is just working for one local machine, I have to modify it for client machines separately, so it will not be an option. Is setting up a dns server the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either distributing a hosts file or leveraging DNS is the only way to accomplish this.